# Update tsvector update trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, tsvector

I have the following tsvector update trigger for a tsvector column 'user_tsv' on a table that allows me to perform full text searches,

```
CREATE TRIGGER tsvector_user_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
tsvector_update_trigger(user_tsv, 'pg_catalog.english', firstname, surname, email);
CREATE INDEX user_index_tsv ON users USING gin(user_tsv);
```

I have since added another column to the table that I want to include in this trigger, is there any way to update the trigger (and also the tsvector column) or do I need to drop the column / trigger and re-add them?

PostgreSQL 9.0

Thanks in advance

David

Comment: You can only rename or enable / disable a trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to drop the column or the index, just drop and re-create the trigger and update any changed fields.

Drop the trigger with a regular `DROP TRIGGER` statement, then re-create it with the new column using `tsvector_update_trigger`, all in the same transaction. Now `UPDATE tablename SET user_tsv = ... WHERE new_column IS NOT NULL` to update the column if you've already added columns. Examine the sources for the tsvector update trigger to find out the appropriate expression to use in the assignment.

Comment: Thanks Craig, this worked a treat, although didnt need to update the tsv column manually, a dummy update statement did it automatically for me